# Specified cast is not valid in HttpClient request

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I am working on an app using xamarin.forms, when doing a GET request to display CompanyName and CompanyLogo in the view it throws the following exception : **Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. occurred**. Any help on how to fix this will be appreciated. Thanks. Below is my code.

**My Json Response:**

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "Token": "K6Zi8VXfqWuthxgn3YEfrU6Bj/EKM7BqvSZcatFgvMx408yadbE+Qj6IuTnZ++C9q4Ty1W2f1quNYMKZxFBNZg==",
        "Authenticated": true,
        "SecretKey": null
    },
    "Companies": [
        {
            "CustomerID": 2,
            "CompanyName": "Posworx",
            "CompanyLogo": "\\admin.loyaltyworx.co.za\\Images\\LOYALTY-LW.png",
            "Stores": [
                {
                    "StoreID": 2,
                    "StoreNumber": null,
                    "StoreName": "Pos Store",
                    "StoreAddress": "218 Stamford Hill Road",
                    "StoreCity": "Durban",
                    "StoreRegion": "KZN",
                    "StoreCountry": "South Africa"
                },
                {
                    "StoreID": 4,
                    "StoreNumber": null,
                    "StoreName": "Pos Store",
                    "StoreAddress": "218 Mathews Meyiwa Road",
                    "StoreCity": "Durban",
                    "StoreRegion": "KZN",
                    "StoreCountry": "South Africa"
                },
                {
                    "StoreID": 3021,
                    "StoreNumber": null,
                    "StoreName": "Tes tStore",
                    "StoreAddress": "",
                    "StoreCity": "",
                    "StoreRegion": "",
                    "StoreCountry": ""
                },
                {
                    "StoreID": 3061,
                    "StoreNumber": null,
                    "StoreName": "tEST",
                    "StoreAddress": "",
                    "StoreCity": "Durban",
                    "StoreRegion": "",
                    "StoreCountry": ""
                }

            ]
        }
    ],
    "IsError": false,
    "ErrorMessage": null
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class Store
        {
            public class Credentials
            {
                public string Token { get; set; }
                public bool Authenticated { get; set; }
                public object SecretKey { get; set; }
            }

            public class StoreDetails
            {
                public int StoreID { get; set; }
                public object StoreNumber { get; set; }
                public string StoreName { get; set; }
                public string StoreAddress { get; set; }
                public string StoreCity { get; set; }
                public string StoreRegion { get; set; }
                public string StoreCountry { get; set; }
            }

            public class Company
            {
                public int CustomerID { get; set; }
                public string CompanyName { get; set; }
                public string CompanyLogo { get; set; }
                public IList<Store> Stores { get; set; }
            }

            public class Stores
            {
                public Credentials Credentials { get; set; }
                public IList<Company> Companies { get; set; }
                public bool IsError { get; set; }
                public object ErrorMessage { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

**Request:**

```
public async void LoadData()
        {
            Store.Stores store = new Store.Stores();
            try
            {
                var content = "";
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var RestUrl = "/api/Company/GetCustomerCompanies";
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RestUrl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Giftworx-App", "K6Zi8VXfqWuthxgn3YEfrU6Bj/EKM7BqvSZcatFgvMx408yadbE+Qj6IuTnZ++C9q4Ty1W2f1quNYMKZxFBNZg==");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(RestUrl);
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(content);
                JObject objResponse = (JObject)jsonResponse["Companies"];
                Dictionary<string, JArray> Items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JArray>>(objResponse.ToString());


                MainListView.ItemsSource = Items.ToList();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string exception = ex.Message;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Async methods should not return void. You cannot await them and therefore you cannot handle exceptions. Also, why don't you just deserialize to `Store` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize into a dictionary on this line:

```
Dictionary<string, JArray> Items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JArray>>(objResponse.ToString());
```

Try using the class you created:

```
var Items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stores>(content);
```

Comment: should be DeserializeObject<Stores>

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modeling a class based on a JSON could be problematic. Make sure your model class is exactly in accordance with your JSON, as well check corresponding data types.

Here is a link to create a C# class based on a JSON string:
http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Further to this, in visual studio you can simply copy the JSON to the clipboard and go Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as classes